# scp command fails with syntax error when used in a bin/sh script

Tags: bash, syntax, sh, glob

The following command works perfectly when called directly from the terminal

```sh
scp -r ./!(node_modules|public) $SERVER:$WEBSITE_SRC
```

but when the same command is added to a shell script it fails with the following error

```
line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

here is the script for reference:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

SERVER=127.0.0.1
WEBSITE_SRC=~/website/src

echo "Deploying changes to the website src code"
scp ./.env* $SERVER:$WEBSITE_SRC
scp -r ./!(node_modules|public) $SERVER:$WEBSITE_SRC
```

Comment: When you call it "directly from the terminal", what shell are you using? Bash? Zsh?

Comment: bash, but it also doesn't matter, when I use `#!bin/bash` I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I've updated the values of the server and website src to be able to replicate that locally as well

Comment: `#!bin/bash` is wrong. How are you running your script?

Comment: just by calling `./filename.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!(node_modules|public)` is extended [globbing syntax](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching). You should do two things.

1. Change the shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` to make sure your script is run by bash.
2. Put `shopt -s extglob` near the top to enable extended globbing syntax.

If it works interactively, it's probably because you have [`shopt -s extglob`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) in one of your shell initialization files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: BTW, it also works with `#!/bin/sh`, but thanks, it works perfectly

Comment: @a14m Only on systems where `/bin/sh` is actually bash. I'm pretty sure it would fail on e.g. Debian-based systems. It's not portable.